# ProgressDialog is not showing even I am using a Thread for the task

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I have this (inside onCreate() method):

```
                    private ProgressDialog pDialog; //(this is in the header)
                    .
                    . 
                    .
                    //This is onCreate() method
                    pDialog=new ProgressDialog(MenuActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.downloading));
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    ...some lines of code...
                    pDialog.show();
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            resultados=timeConsumingTask();
                        }
                    });
                    thread.start();
                    try {
                        thread.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if(resultados.contains(1)){
                        if(pDialog!=null){
                            if(pDialog.isShowing()){
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                        doSomething();
                    }else{
                        if(pDialog!=null){
                            if(pDialog.isShowing()){
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                        doOtherThing();
                    {
```

I have looked at every tutorial and every answer here at SO. Everyone of them says that you must do pDialog.show(); just before the time consuming task, but obviously I am missing something, since the pDialog is never shown.

Can you help me to show it, and to dismiss it inside the if?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Maybe is relevant that I am calling the show() method and everything in the onClick() method of a FloatingActionButton)

Comment: can you please post pDialog object initialization code here?

Comment: Sure, I am going to edit my question.

Comment: Diloag which is a UI component should be used in conjunction with main ui thread and not background threads

Comment: It is shown in main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the UI is blocked on some point the Dialog will not be shown.

The line  `thread.join();` is blocking your UI thread.

Try using an AsyncTask instead a Thread and put on AsyncTask.onPostExecute() the code to be executed after the thread terminates.

Comment: Removing the join(); and moving the if to another method, invoked from inside the thread(), did the trick. Also, I had to dismiss the pDialog() inside a runOnUiThreadMethod. Your answer put me in the right track. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To render any of the UI part activity OnCreate() function call must have to be finished/completed.

Since you are trying to show and hide the progress dialog from the same function it does not give effect of showing on screen.

Also by doing thread.join() you are blocking the main threat which prevents the OnCreate() completion and result in showing and hiding progress dialog within onCreate()

Solution: Try to perform your timeConsumingTask() on thread without thread.join() and use runOnUiThread() method to hide the progressDialog from thread itself